# Find the last of an annotated record in Django

Tags: python, django, django-models

So I have 2 models: `Products` and `Profile`.

GOAL: I would like to find all the Wishlist that share the same `Product` and `Profile` and delete the last Wishlist for that `Profile`.

Basically, there should not be a Waitlist with the same `Profile` and `Product`. My goal is to delete the duplicate.

models.py

```
class Wishlist(BaseModel):
    class Product:
        TOYS = 't'
        CLOTHES = 'c'

    PRODUCT_CHOICES = (
        (Product.TOYS, 'toys'),
        (Products.CLOTHES, 'clothes'),
    )

    profile = models.ForeignKey(Profile)
    product = models.CharField(max_length=2, choices=PRODUCT_CHOICES, null=True, blank=True)

class Profile(BaseModel):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

This is what I tried:

```
duplicates = (
    Waitlist.objects
    .values('profile', 'product')
    .annotate(Count('profile'))
    .filter(profile__count__gt=1)
)

for dup in duplicates:
    profile_id = dup['profile']
    profile = Profile.get_by_id(profile_id)
    last_product_waitlist = profile.productwaitlist_set.latest('timestamp')
    last_product_waitlist.delete()
```

I'm trying to see if I can do this in one Django query.

Comment: Can you share the models? Just the specific relationship fields will do

Comment: The code you shared seems to only find `Waitlist`s with multiple profiles, products are ignored?

Comment: @IainShelvington Just updated the description.

Comment: Are you using postgres as your DB? Just to be clear, you want the latest `Waitlist` by `timestamp` for each `Profile`?

Comment: @IainShelvington i'm using PostgreSQL. You are correct. But I need to first find if there is a duplicate Waitlist with the same Profile and Product. I don't care about the non duplicates.

Comment: Can you share `BaseModel` as well?